# String parameters in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

Im having a function:

```
<script>
function params(a,b,c,d) {
// alert (c); 
var question = document.getElementById("question");
question.value = c;
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
answer.value = d;
var catid = document.getElementById("catid");
catid.value = a;
var qid = document.getElementById("qid");
qid.value = b;
}

<button class="modalInput" rel="#prompt" onClick="params(29,29,'In a FOX TV show, what did &#039;The OC&#039; stand for','Orange County');"><img src=/images/exclamationmark1.png title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." ></button>


<button class="modalInput" rel="#prompt" onClick="params(29,16,'Which reality show is named after a George Orwell character','Big Brother');"><img src=/images/exclamationmark1.png title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." ></button>
```

First button doesnt Work, because of the #&039; - Second one does... But the first one did come from using htmlspecialchars() on a string... So I thought this would do the trick?

You can see the page its on here:

http://www.quizboard-cheat.com/component/com_rquote/Itemid,176/catid,29/number_items,999/quotation_marks,0/show_author,1/show_createdate,0/show_notes,0/show_quote,1/sort_column,0/sort_order,0/view,rquotes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the HTML that needs to be escaped there. The HTML character escape sequence `&#039;` will yield a single apostrophe, so the JavaScript code you get is

```
params(29,29,'In a FOX TV show, what did 'The OC' stand for','Orange County');
```

Obviously a syntax error. You just would need to escape the string delimiters with a backslash:

```xml
<button … onClick="params(29,29,'In a … did \'The OC\' stand for',…);">
```

Or you would need to use quotes as string delimiters - which then would indeed need to be HTML-escaped, since they are used as HTML attribute delimiters:

```xml
<button … onClick="params(29,29,&#034;In a … did 'The OC' stand for&#034;,…);">
```

---

Of course, @Kirill Ivlev is right. You shouldn't have used inline event handler attributes in the first place, but [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). If you attach your listeners from scripts code, you won't have any encoding problems.

Comment: Another way to think about it is: the whole button tag is _rendered_ by the browser.  The browser converts those html entities to quote mark characters.  Later, when a user clicks on the button, the text including the quote mark characters is sent to the javascript function.

Comment: @7stud: Now, not exactly (replace *render* with *parse* and the JS will be parsed as well before it is interpreted) but the idea gets it right…

Comment: Yeah, I was not satisfied with my explanation after I posted it.

Answer (score 3):

`htmlspecialchars` will stop the character from causing problems to the HTML. When the attribute value is parsed it is converted back to `'` before being passes to the JS engine and at that point it breaks the string. You need to escape it with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://jsbin.com/uwedoj/1/edit), you can escape characteres with backslash, is an option:

```
\'The OC\'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in Firebug is:

```
params(29,29,'In a FOX TV show, what did 'The OC' stand for','Orange County');
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). Instead of jamming everything into an inline click handler where you have to escape it not only for HTML but also for JS, put each of the parameters in a separate `data-paramname` attribute. Aside from making escaping easier to manage, it will also make the code cleaner and easier to read.

```
<div id="questioncontainer">
  <button class="modalInput" rel="#prompt" data-catid="29" data-qid="29"
    data-question="In a FOX TV show, what did &#039;The OC&#039; stand for"
    data-answer="Orange County"><img src=/images/exclamationmark1.png
    title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." >Q1</button>
  <button class="modalInput" rel="#prompt" data-catid="29" data-qid="16"
    data-question="Which reality show is named after a George Orwell character"
    data-answer="Big Brother"><img src=/images/exclamationmark1.png
    title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." >Q2</button>
</div>
```

The below code uses [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) to attach a single event handler to handle all of the `modalinput` buttons inside it.

```
(function () { // prevent our vars from leaking into the global name-space
  "use strict";
  // querying the DOM is slow, we will be accessing
  // these elements frequently, store references to them
  var question = document.getElementById("question"),
    answer = document.getElementById("answer"),
    catid = document.getElementById("catid"),
    qid = document.getElementById("qid"),

    displayQuestion =  function (evt) {
      var target = evt.target,
        getData = function (name) {
          return target.getAttribute('data-' + name);
        };

      if (target.className.match(/\bmodalinput\b/i)) {
        question.value = getData('question');
        answer.value = getData('answer');
        catid.value = getData('catid');
        qid.value = getData('qid');
      }
    },
    questionContainer = document.getElementById('questioncontainer');

  questionContainer.addEventListener('click', displayQuestion, false);
}());
```

[Functioning example](http://jsfiddle.net/etdNE/1/)